# Why do optocouplers require a resistor at the collector?

Tags: resistors, opto-isolator, resistor-transistor-logic

[image: Optocoupler Circuit]

In this circuit, if the resistor in the collector **R1 is 0 Ohms**, the circuit doesn't work. That is, the output will be 12V DC signal as it is from the battery. And if **R1 is non-zero**, then the circuit works and produces expected output. Can someone explain me why that resistance (R1) is required in this circuit?

Comment: Perhaps an equally interesting question: why is there no resistor in series with the input diode?

Comment: As I understand, for optocouplers like **MCT2E**, the Input-diode continuous forward current is about **60 mA**. Thus if we are using a 5v logic supply to drive the opto, then there should be a **83.5 Ohms/0.3Watts** resistor used in the input as well. Please correct me if I'm wrong. MCT2E datasheet is available here : http://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheets/90/424848_DS.pdf

Comment: sounds reasonable. I just wanted to point out there are other problems with this circuit. Also, you wouldn't want to operate close to the absolute maximum, and most circuits don't require full current driving capability of the optocouple, so will use a larger resistor, like maybe \$4.7k\Omega\$. It depends on how much input current is required to get the output to saturate, which depends on R1 and the optocoupler's characteristics.

Comment: I would go far away from opto-coupler as there are many options these days. If you're trying to isolate fast signals, then you're going to have to calculate the rise/fall time which means you'll need to size your resistor correctly. Way too much work when you can just get a small IC that does everything for you. For example, you can get something like a ADuM1200 from analog devices for isolation. No need for external resistors, and it draws extremely low current. For bidirectional you could try the ADuM1250.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine an optocoupler's output as a device which is willing to pass through a light-dependent amount of current whenever the collector voltage is higher than the emitter voltage (in practice, the amount of current is a complicated function of the amount of light and the amount by which the collector voltage exceeds the emitter voltage).  With no light, it will pass 10 microamps, and its current-passing capacity will "peg" at 100mA.  If the current limit of the opto is I, the voltage at the collector will be 12V-IR or zero volts, whichever is less.

If the resistor were e.g. 1 meg, the amount of volt dropped by the resistor would be a minimum of 10 volts, meaning the collector voltage would never get above 2 volts.  Cutting that resistor to 500K would reduce its minimum voltage drop to 5 volts, allowing the collector up to 7.  Cutting it to 100K would reduce the voltage drop to 1 volt, allowing the collector up to 11 volts.  The smaller the resistor, the higher the voltage when the opto is "off", approaching but not quite reaching a limit of the full 12 volts.

On the flip side, when the opto is on, the voltage drop across the resistor will be 100mA times the resistance or 12 volts, whichever is lower.  If the resistor value is 120 ohms or less, the 12 volt supply will me the limiting factor.  If the resistor were e.g. 100 ohms, the resistor voltage would be limited to 10 volts, meaning the collector voltage would only get down to 2 volts.  Note that if the resistor is large enough, further improvements won't affect the voltage, but if it's too small, the output voltage will be quite sensitive to resistance.

Comment: "the voltage at the collector will be 12V-IR **or zero volts**, whichever is less." Why there is a concept of zero volts? It should always be ```(12 - I*R)``` correct?

Comment: @Napster: I specified that the current *limit* of the Opto was designated by **I**.  If 12-I*R would go negative, that means that the actual amount of current in the opto will be some smaller value.

Answer (score 7):

With R1 set to 0 Ohms, the optocoupler can draw a current as usual. But that won't produce any voltage variation at the oscilloscope input. Because the 'scope will be essentially short circuited to a voltage source.

When R1 is nonzero, the optocoupler current flows through the resistor and is converted to a voltage according to Ohm's law: V = I R. This voltage variation is what the oscilloscope is able to measure.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is stupid but, In the R1=0 Ohm situation, when the internal transistor starts to conduct (when the internal LED blinks), the 12V supply will be short circuited to the *ground* via the CE junction, right? And since the supply is grounded, scope should read 0v, am I right?

Comment: In that scenario, when the optocoupler is active, it doesn't act like a short circuit, it acts like a current source (actually, current sink). Only if the current it's sinking is enough to pull the collector side down to zero (because of having a resistor at the R1 location) would you say it's acting like a short circuit.

Answer (score 1):

What you show there is a simulation software, called Multisim. The simulated battery has infinitely small resistance and in your simulation the voltage will not drop as it would with a real battery. Therefore if you remove , or 0, R1, then the only resistor is the transistor  - which will develop across it 12V, regardless of the tremendous current draw which would have (a) blown the transistor (b) drain the battery resulting in some voltage drop, depending on the size of the battery. In most cases I can imagine, the transistor would blow pretty quick.

You also said "And if R1 is non-zero,  then the circuit works " - well no, it does not. Again, if R1 is too low you will end up pulling too much current out of the battery and you will blow the transistor. And Multisim will not show you the transient voltage drop at the battery's terminals just before the transistor goes up in smoke.

And the same applies to the driving diode, without some means of limiting the current it too would probably burn in real life.